# NiceAlert (suppresses JavaScript alert) equivalent extension for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript, alert

I live in South Korea which is full of cheap web programmers who don't understand accessibilty or cross-platform, etc. Many major Korean web sites are built by those kind of programmers and managers.

So, there are some Korean web sites I have to use. One of the problems is that they tend to show lots of unnecessary modal (blocking) `alert()` for things I do not have to confirm. For example, `alert("You are logged in.")`, `alert("The item is added to the cart.")`, `alert("The number is updated.")`, etc. I do NOT care those messages. On Safari and Chrome, I have installed an extension called "NiceAlert" which transforms the modal alert box into a modeless(non-blocking) popup on the top-right corner of the page.

Those stupid Korean sites require lots of ActiveX controls and do not work well with browsers other than Internet Explorer, so I am forced to use IE. I know there is a similar question here, but it was asked 3 years ago, and there aren't any helpful answers to me. Has the situation changed in 2014? Is there any such extension?